# Get elements out of list in python

Tags: python, list

Hi i just started with python and have a pretty nooby question.

I have a list which looks like this:

```
[(1.0, 'Test1'), (1,3 'Test2'), (1.4 'Test3')]
```

How can i get only "Test1 Test2 Test3" as a return?

best regards

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> L = [(1.0, 'Test1'), (1.3, 'Test2'), (1.4, 'Test3')]
>>> [x[1] for x in L]
['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']

>>> " ".join(x[1] for x in L)
'Test1 Test2 Test3'
```

You could also use `itemgetter(1)`, but the methods above would generally be preferred

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> " ".join(map(itemgetter(1), L))
'Test1 Test2 Test3'
```

Comment: The second item in the list (not sure if this is a typo) is `(1,3 'Test2')`, so this would give you `'Test1 3 Test3'` (Actually, it would throw an exception when you tried to join the integer).

Comment: @willy, no, in that case it's a SyntaxError anyway.

Comment: My bad, can't brain today, I read that as `(1,3,'Test2')`

Answer (score 0):

Just a space joining a list comprehension grabbing the last item of each tuple, or:

```
    items = [(1.0, 'Test1'), (1,3 'Test2'), (1.4 'Test3')]
    return " ".join([item[-1] for item in items])
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the list `['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']` you could do:

```
list = [(1.0, 'Test1'), (1.3, 'Test2'), (1.4, 'Test3')]
newlist = []
for (key, value) in list:
    newlist.append(value)
```

Then `newlist` will be `['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']`
or just

```
newlist = [value for (key, value) in list]
```

This uses Python's tuple unpacking to get the second element of each tuple in your list. See http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences for more information about tuples.

You can create the string `'Test1 Test2 Test3'` using `''.join` as other answers mention:

```
' '.join(newlist)
```